# Response data ignore property

Tags: java, json

Can a JSON response be ignored when the response server sends the result?

I mean, response server (A) send response data object like `{"A" : 'SOME_DATA'}`.

And it changed `{"A" : 'SOME_DATA', "B" : 'SOME_DATA_2'}`, and if request server (B) does not update the data object then a "JSON unrecognized error" occurs.

So, I want that make object but, if server B cannot recognized, than I don't send "B".

It can be possible setting on server A? or it is must set on server B, annotation like `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`?

Comment: If you let "server B" (I think you mean "client B") send a header along with the request that contains a version number for the response that it can accept, then "server A" can choose between several different responses depending on the version that B specified. But it's probably easier if you tell your clients up-front to ignore unknown fields.

Comment: thanks to advise. than you mean "server A" cannot handle about response property in own server? like @jsonignore? there is no way to handle it in server side(mean, server A).

Answer (score 0):

The best practices when you want to make an update on your API is to create a new endpoint for your new version. Something like this :

api/v1/my/awesome/endpoint

api/v2/my/awesome/endpoint

For ignore response part of JSON you can indeed put on the client DTO

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```